# How do I force leaflet to update the map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I'm running into issues as I am using Leaflet together with React, the issue being that Leaflet wants to control the DOM rendering as well, as far as I've researched.

Right now, the countries will correctly be colored with the specific color code corresponding with the backend information(range of 1-->100). However, it is updated every minute. Upon update, the country color will not change. It will however if you hover the mouse over a given country, which is a bit weird.

Here's my source code:

```
import React from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import countries from './countries.js';


var Worldmap = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        if(!this.props.data)
            return <div> loading world map ..  </div>;

        let dataratio = this.props.data; // Props from main component
        let size = Object.keys(dataratio).length; // Do we have data?

        if(size > 1) { // If we do have data, ..

            let dataratioToArr = Object.keys(dataratio).map(data => [ data, dataratio[data]]); // Conv. map to multidimensional array

            let featuresArr = countries.features; // array of all countries in array features from countries.js

            for(let i = 0; i < featuresArr.length; i++) // i = 178(no. of countries)
                for(let j = 0; j < dataratioToArr.length; j++) // j = no. of countries we have with dataratio > 1 from backend
                    if(dataratioToArr[j][0] == featuresArr[i].id) // If ISO-3 compliant ID of country(f.e. "USA") matches, push a "data" property to countries.js
                        featuresArr[i].properties.data = dataratioToArr[j][1];
        }

        return(
            <div id="leafletmap" style={{width: "100%", height: "80%", border: "2px solid black" }} />
        )
    },

    componentDidMount : function() {
        let geolocation =  [];
        // Retrieve geoloc coordinates
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            let lat = position.coords.latitude;
            let lon = position.coords.longitude;

            if(lat != null && lon != null) // If we can get latitude and longitude, reset geolocation and push values.
                geolocation.length = 0;
            geolocation.push(lat, lon);
            if(!lat || !lon) // If we can't get latitude or longitude, set a default value.
                geolocation = [0,0];

            let map = L.map('leafletmap').setView(geolocation, 3); // ([coordinates], zoomlevel)

            let info = L.control();

            info.onAdd = function (map) {
                this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
                this.update();
                return this._div;
            };

            info.update = function (props) {
                this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Data ratio</h4>' +  (props ?
                    '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.data + ' ratio'
                        : 'Hover over a country');
            };

            info.addTo(map);


            function getColor(d) {
                return d > 90 ? '#4a1486' :
                    d > 75  ? '#6a51a3' :
                        d > 50  ? '#807dba' :
                            d > 25  ? '#9e9ac8' :
                                d > 15   ? '#bcbddc' :
                                    d > 5   ? '#dadaeb' :
                                        d > 1   ? '#f2f0f7' :
                                            '#D3D3D3'; // Default color of data doesn't exist or is 0.
            }


            function style(feature) {
                return {
                    weight: 2,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 'white',
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.data)
                };
            }

            function highlightFeature(e) {
                let layer = e.target;

                layer.setStyle({
                    weight: 5,
                    color: '#666',
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                });

                if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera && !L.Browser.edge) {
                    layer.bringToFront();
                }

                info.update(layer.feature.properties);
            }

            let geojson;

            function resetHighlight(e) {
                geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
                info.update();
            }

            function zoomToFeature(e) {
                map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
            }

            function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                layer.on({
                    mouseover: highlightFeature,
                    mouseout: resetHighlight,
                    click: zoomToFeature
                });
            }


            geojson = L.geoJson(countries, { // from import
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }).addTo(map);

            let legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

            legend.onAdd = function (map) {

                let div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                    grades = [1, 5, 15, 25, 50, 75, 90],
                    labels = [],
                    from, to;

                for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                    from = grades[i];
                    to = grades[i + 1];

                    labels.push(
                        '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                        from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '+'));
                }

                div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
                return div;
            };

            legend.addTo(map);
        });

    }
});

export default Worldmap
```

How do I force leaflet to redraw or refresh the map upon a new `this.props.data` being received?

I tried using `componentDidUpdate` where I basically would do `map.remove()`, but then I run into scoping issues between the different components.. It's all loaded in `componentDidMount` and if you call the leaflet map again it will say it's already initialized.

Comment: try to use React-Leaflet that will make the management of react life cycles and the map easier https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet  But as a possible solution direction in your case you should clearLayers on each new data update in 
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.data !== this.props.data) {
      youMapRef.clearLayers(); } }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend my comment.
You need to clear the layer and and re-add data to your map. It's possible that in your case you will need to change how you access the map and geojson processing but I'm giving you the general solution here.

```
   componentDidMount(){
      var map = this.map = L.map('leafletmap');
   } 


   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.data !== this.props.data) {
       this.map.clearLayers();
      }
   } 


  componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
      if (prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
          this.map.addData(geojsonData);
       }
   }
```

Comment: You're initializing the map again in a different component, that would throw an error and not render the map as far as I can tell? Since it's already created elsewhere. Specifically, `Map container is already initialized.`

Comment: Updated the answer with a possible way to access the map component

Comment: I am not certain what exactly it is you are suggesting(though I get the idea). Your example would result in `Uncaught TypeError: this.map.clearLayers is not a function` since there is a scoping issue present.