# How to update leaflet map with `getDerivedStateFromProps` from React 16.3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

Now that `componentWillReceiveProps` is going to be deprecated how would you update a leaflet map with the new `getDerivedStateFromProps` workflow.

This is what I do now:

1. I load the map in `componentDidMount` and draw elements
2. If there is a prop update I clear the layers and redraw the elements in `componentDidUpdate`.

This is some sample code:

```
componentDidMount(){
  // load leaflet map and draw components
  var map = this.map = L.map('leafletmap');
  this.map.addData(geojsonData);
} 

componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
  // clear layers and redraw data
  if (prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
      this.map.clearLayers();
      this.map.addData(geojsonData);
   }
 }
```

I have to do it this way since `componentDidMount` is only called once and `componentDidUpdate` is only called after a prop update. I think I could use either `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps` in my workflow. Now that `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and considering that `getDerivedStateFromProps` is always called I would like to know if I can draw all my leaflet stuff on this step and if this should be enough to update the map wherever props are changed.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
  // draw stuff on map every time props change 
  // (layers should be cleared as well)
  if (prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
      this.map.clearLayers();
      this.map.addData(geojsonData);
   }
 } 

componentDidMount(){
  // load leaflet map
  var map = this.map = L.map('leafletmap');
}
```

The problem I have is that I can't access `this` in `getDerivedStateFromProps`
Related: [How do I force leaflet to update the map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926234/how-do-i-force-leaflet-to-update-the-map)

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` is made static on purpose. Because the method happens before the 'commit' stage, it can be called multiple times when a render is suspended. `getDerivedStateFromProps` is not the place to do side effects.

Answer (score 0):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is intended to only update/set the state based on prop and not to perform any side-effect,

The `componentWillReceiveProps` function can be broken down into

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
   //returning the updated state if you want 
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   //perform side-effects based on props or state change
}
```

In your case you would write

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.data !== this.props.data) {
      this.map.clearLayers();
      this.map.addData(geojsonData);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think I could use either `componentDidUpdate` or `componentWillReceiveProps` in my workflow.

As Wazner's comment mentions above, this isn't quite right. Side effects (what you're describing) are not safe in `componentWillReceiveProps` or `getDerivedStateFromProps`. The [`StrictMode` docs page has a section that goes into more detail on why this is](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects).

For the case you're describing, it's unclear to me why you can't just continue to use `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` as your sample code shows. (Since you weren't using `componentWillReceiveProps` before- why change now?)

Comment: I can continue to use it, there is no problem at all. I just wanted to know if with the new method I could do everything in one step instead of in two

Comment: Ah! I see. :) Thanks for clarifying. No, `getDerivedStateFromProps` isn't meant for this sort of thing. You'd still want to use did-mount and did-update.